# Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration with Fortify Java 1.8 EJB

Tags: java, security, java-8, ejb, fortify

I am trying to solve some vulnerabilities issues, and I have one that I couldn't solve it, I tried to add @Valid annotation in sync method but same error, this is the description from fortify:

> The framework binder used for binding the HTTP request parameters to
> the model class has not been explicitly configured to allow, or
> disallow certain attributes.
>
> To ease development and increase productivity, most modern frameworks
> allow an object to be automatically instantiated and populated with
> the HTTP request parameters whose names match an attribute of the
> class to be bound. Automatic instantiation and population of objects
> speeds up development, but can lead to serious problems if implemented
> without caution. Any attribute in the bound classes, or nested
> classes, will be automatically bound to the HTTP request parameters.
> Therefore, malicious users will be able to assign a value to any
> attribute in bound or nested classes, even if they are not exposed to
> the client through web forms or API contracts.

The error I am getting in this line:

> public ResponseClass sync(@BeanParam MyClassRequest request) throws
> Exception {

MyClassResource.java

```
@Api(tags = "Relay")
@Stateless
public class MyClassResource extends AbstractService<MyClassRequest, ResponseClass> {
 
    @EJB
    private MyClassService myClassService;

    @POST
    @Path("/api/v1/service")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    @ApiOperation(value = "Processes Conn",
            response = ResponseClass.class, responseContainer = "ResponseClass", hidden = true)
    @Override
    public ResponseClass sync(@BeanParam MyClassRequest request) throws Exception {
        myClassService.processFeed(request);
        return new RelayResponse(HttpStatuses.ACCEPTED.getStatus());
    }
```

MyClassRequest.java

In this file I have tried @FormParam("ccc") but same

```
public class MyClassRequest extends RelayRequest {

    public MyClassRequest() {
        super.setMessageType("not required");
    }

    private String myData;
    private String conneRid;
    private String connectionCreatedDate;
```

If someone could give some hint that how I can solve it, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect all fields to be present in request? You are using `@Valid` annotation but there are no validation annotations in `MyClassRequest` model. Try to add some validation annotations like `@JsonIgnore` for non mandatory fields. Or `@JsonInclude` on class. If this does not help, may be also try explicitly adding `@JsonProperty` on each field.

Comment: the idea was good, as you said in this case I have to indicate which fields have to be present in request in my case with @FormParam("fieldName") in Request class, and I have to use @Valid as well in Resource class. that is the solution, thanks Shivaji